# How a second test influences probability of having disease

Tags: probability

Suppose the probability to have a certain disease is $P(D)=1/2$.
A patient, after having a medical test, is told by the doctor: "We have results, they are negative (you don't have the disease) at 95%".

I think that means $P(D^\complement|negative \space result)=0.95$.

Now the question:

> if I remake the test, and the results are negative which value does the probability $P(D^\complement|(negative \space 1st)\cap(negative \space 2nd))$ assumes?

---

This is what I try:

Let $D$=disease, and $neg_i$=i test is negative.

$$P(D^c|neg_1 \cap neg_2)=\frac{P(neg_1 \cap neg_2|D^c)P(D^c)}{P(neg_1 \cap neg_2|D^c)P(D^c)+P(neg_1 \cap neg_2|D)P(D)}=\frac{P(neg|D^c)^2}{P(neg|D^c)^2+P(neg|D)^2}$$

And then?

Comment: You can still apply Bayes'rule

Comment: I do it but it seems like I need more information about the test

Comment: You need the probabilities that the test is negative twice given the patient has the disease and given the patient does not have the desease. This should be sufficient.

Comment: I ended exactly with these conclusion. I post the question to see if it was an error in my reasoning. So without those informations is impossible to answer the question?

Comment: Yes, we need them. But it is sufficient to know the probabilities for a single test if we assume independence of the two tests. Which informations do we have in the exercise ?

Comment: This is not an exercise taken from a book, I was wondering about it :(
Referring to the exercise I can't see how to do, I'll add in the answer what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \begin{eqnarray*}  
P(neg| D^c)=P(D^c | neg)\frac{P(neg)}{P(D^c)}=(0.95)(2)P(neg)
\\P(neg| D)=P(D | neg)\frac{P(neg)}{P(D)}=(0.05)(2)P(neg)
\end{eqnarray*} $$
the factors of $(2)P(neg)$ will cancel, so you are left with.

$$ P(D^c|n_1\cup n_2)=\frac{(0.95)^2}{(0.95)^2+(0.05)^2} \approx 0.99723 $$

This is also what you would get if you recognized that you are either sick or well

so either the test is right both times - $P_{rr}=(0.95)^2$
or the test is wrong both times - $P{ww}=(.05)^2$

So the total probability of the situation described is  $P_{sit}  = P_{rr} + P_{ww}$

And the conditional probability of the test being right both times is 
$$ P(D^c|n_1\cup n_2)=\frac{P_{rr}}{P_{sit}  } \approx 0.99723 $$

It is also super close to what you would get if you just said that the probability of the test being wrong both times is $(0.05)^2$ so the probability of being right both times is $1-(0.05)^2=0.9975$